# I can't install Android SDK

Tags: android

I just started to work with Android Studio and I stuck with one problem .It shows this message when it tries to install the sdk
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86_64-33_r06.zip
Unfortunately it doesn't do anything even if you wait for hours please help me to solve this problem thanks

Comment: Tool -> SDK Manger -> choose your SDK and install

Answer (score 0):

Check for space available on your disk

else

reinstall android studio

Comment: Can you share the Android Studio version?

Comment: VERSION 2021.3.1.17